error when starting dev server: Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, rmdir
error when starting dev server:
Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, rmdir 'C:\Users\user_name\OneDrive\Documents\edusity\node_modules.vite\deps'
I run a command "npm install react-scroll" after that it throw a error
if anyone know the solution let me know i am stuck in the problem from last week i tried almost every solution which are present in stack overflow and youtube.

try to re-run command in admin mode.
